# JMeter: Recallable BeanShell Assertion?

Tags: api, jmeter

I'm performing API testing of basic CRUD functionality. For the creation of each record type in each thread group, I am using the same BeanShell Assertion template customized to each thread group.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

if (ResponseCode != null && ResponseCode.equals("200") == true) {
SampleResult.setResponseOK();  
}
else if (!ResponseCode.equals ("200") == true ) { 
    Failure = true;
    FailureMessage ="Creation of a new {insert record type} record failed. Response code " + ResponseCode + "." ; // displays in Results Tree
    print ("Creation of a new {insert record type} record failed: Response code  " + ResponseCode + ".");   // goes to stdout
    log.warn("Creation of a new {insert record type} record failed: Response code " + ResponseCode); // this goes to the JMeter log file

// Static elements or calculations
part1 = "\n FAILED TO CREATE NEW {insert record type} RECORD via POST. The response code is: \"";
part2 = "\". \n\n - For \'Non-HTTP response code - org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException\' is received,verify the payload file still exists. \n - For response code = 409, \n\t a) check the payload for validity.\n\t b) verify the same {insert record type} name doesn't already exist in the {insert table name} table. If found, delete record and re-run the test. \n - For response code = 500, verify the database and its host server are reachable. \n";

// Open File(s)
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + "\\error.log", true);

//FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("c:\\error.log", true); 
PrintStream p = new PrintStream(f); 

// Write data to file 
p.println( part1 + ResponseCode + part2 );

// Close File(s)
p.close();
f.close();
}
```

**Is there a way to make this re-callable as opposed to having to repeat it in each thread group?** Right now I'm up to 20 thread groups, thus 20 versions of this same assertion.

I've looked at multiple pages on this site and also at [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell), but I'm not finding a solution to this. Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place your Assertion (any Assertion) at the same level as Thread Groups like:

[image: Assertion Thread Groups]

It will be applied to both "Sampler 1" and "Sampler 2". Moreover, the assertion will be applied to each sampler in each thread group on each iteration.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide which clarifies assertions scope, cost and best practices.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot.